# Digital camera download software?

Tags: download, camera

We have just bought a Sony DSC-W310 digital camera.

Our old Sony camera came with Image Transfer software that would automatically transfer all photos on the camera into a chosen location in a folder for the current date. This software would run when the camera was plugged in.

Temporarily we used a small 512Mb Memory Stick Pro Duo card that we had and this worked with the Image Transfer software. However, we bought a larger 8Gb SD card for it (it takes both Memory Stick and SD Card). The card works great but is no longer compatible with our Image Transfer software :(

Does anyone have any ideas that could get the Image Transfer software working (registry hacks etc)?

Alternatively is there any free software that can do what I want (automatically copy files to folder inside sub-folder for today's date and then delete the files from the camera) or will I have to write a utility myself??? This must be a common need.

Thanks for any help.

Alan

P.S. The software that came with it looks far too heavy-weight for my needs. It is more of a photo management app rather than the simple utility I am after.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Google's [Picasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picasa)?  I use it for various different cameras & scanners etc.  Should do everything you need (although the deleting does not work for me from PC -> camera, I assume it is camera specific).

Comment: Thanks Phill. I do use Picasa but I wanted a completely automated transfer process (i.e. plug in, copy, delete). My solution was to use the software from a Canon camera that we have.